# How can I integrate Moose into Komodo?

Tags: perl, moose, komodo

ActiveState's [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo/) is my preferred Perl IDE on OS X and XP.  Recently I've begun coding new projects using [Moose](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/print/34119.html).

Has anyone found a way to teach Komodo how to "identify" Moose's Attribute and Method declarations? I would just love to see Moose-Support in the "Code Browser/Code Explorer" of Komodo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching around on activestate's support forums I found, that Komodo has it's own syntax-description language, called **["Luddite"](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/5.1/luddite.html)**, that is used to describe syntax highlighting and other rules for the "user defined" programming languages Komodo supports.

There is even a Luddite [usage example on PHP](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/5.1/udl.html) .. and some "Compiling and Installing" instructions.

I guess the question now is:

**Has anyone worked on a Moose-UDL/Luddite extension for Komodo?**

Answer (score 4):

As a point of reference, PerlySense has a [Moose syntax plugin](http://search.cpan.org/~johanl/Devel-PerlySense-0.0180/lib/Devel/PerlySense/Plugin/Syntax/Moose.pm) for understanding that dialect of Perl. It uses the normal PPI document to look for Moose constructs.